# Youtube (JS chrome extension) - how to know when dynamic page loading is finished?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, dynamic

If you go to youtube.com and open up the Subscriptions column and click different channels, the page will change dynamically. However, weirdly enough, there's no way for a JS script to know:

1. If the page has changed
2. When the page has finished changing/loading

Just do this experiment:

- Go to chrome dev console and type `let body=document.body;`
- Click to a different channel.
- Type in dev console `body===document.body;`

And the result will be `true`

I'm honestly very confused about what's going on and what I can do to go around this.